# What are the differences between the 3 cdn values for SHOPWARE_CDN_STRATEGY_DEFAULT

Tags: shopware

There are 3 different values for the `SHOPWARE_CDN_STRATEGY_DEFAULT`

1. id
2. physical_filename
3. filename

I dont know the differences between the 3. What do they mean? And what is the best strategy for which case?

Answer (score 0):

Shopware generates the media paths using a pathname strategy. The relevant classes can be found in Shopware's core:

`core/Content/Media/Pathname/PathnameStrategy`

Basically there are three predefined strategies: Id, Filename and PhysicalFilename.

The Id strategy simply creates a path based on the md5 hash of the mediaId. Thus there is no relationship between the filename and the generated path, it is impossible to 'guess' the path just knowing the filename.

The Filename strategy does the same, but uses the filename as the basis for the hash. The disadvantage obviously is that you cannot have two media files with the same filename.

The PhysicalFilename strategy adds the uploadedAt timestamp to the filename to create the hash, thus allowing multiple files with the same filename.

For most cases, the preferred strategy is 'Id'. To enable this strategy, define and set the SHOPWARE_CDN_STRATEGY_DEFAULT variable in your .env file.

```
# .env
SHOPWARE_CDN_STRATEGY_DEFAULT="id"
```

There might be cases, where it is desirable to not allow multiple files with the same filename. In this case the Filename strategy will be an option. I can't see a use case for the PhysicalFilename strategy, however.